# How to make toggle dark mode works in all page?

Tags: reactjs

i have problem when i trying to figure it out how `background-color`  change when someone invoke the toggle button. First i try to make color when light and dark and i try to invoke use `data-theme="dark"`, but the color change is just the navbar, I think because I made this `data-theme` inside the navbar div. Then I tried by making the `data-theme` be in main.jsx by giving it a wrapper div but the result was the same. Is there anything that can help how?

```
main.jsx
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import NavbarSection from "./components/nav/NavbarSection";
import FooterSection from "./components/footer/FooterSection"
import "./index.css";

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <NavbarSection />
    <FooterSection/>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

```
index.css:
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```
NavbarSection.jsx:

import './navbar.css'

const NavbarSection = () => {

  return (
    <div className='navbar' data-theme='dark'>
      <p id='name'>Raihan Firdaus</p>

      <ul id='navmenu'>
        <li><a>Home</a></li>
        <li><a>About</a></li>
        <li><a>Projects</a></li>
        <li><a>Contact</a></li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}

export default NavbarSection
```

```
navbar.css:
:root {
  --text-color: #1C1D21;
  --nav-bg: #BFBFBF;
  --footer-bg: #BFBFB;
  --bg: #D9D9D9;
  /* --text-color-light: #1C1D21;
  --nav-bg-light: #BFBFBF;
  --footer-bg-light: #BFBFB;
  --bg-light: #D9D9D9; */
}

[data-theme="dark"] {
  --text-color: #BFBEC1;
  --nav-bg: #45464A;
  --footer-bg: #45464A;
  --bg: #212121;
}

.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: var(--nav-bg);
}

.navbar #name {
  margin-left: 20px;
  font-family: 'Inconsolata', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: var(--text-color);
  background-color: var(--nav-bg);
}

.navbar #navmenu {
  margin-right: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  gap: 1rem;
  background-color: var(--nav-bg);
}

.navbar #navmenu li {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: var(--nav-bg);
  
}

.navbar #navmenu li a {
  color: var(--text-color);
  font-family: 'Inconsolata', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: var(--nav-bg);
}

.navbar #navmenu li a:hover {
  text-decoration-line: underline;
}
```

And also I have tried to make root indexed.css assuming that this root can later be accessed in all CSS then I better put it in the root file.

```
FooterSection.jsx:
import './footer.css'

const FooterSection = () => {
  const getYear = new Date().getFullYear();
  return (
    <footer className='footer'>
    <p>{`Copyright © Raihan Firdaus ${getYear}`}</p>
    </footer>
  )
}

export default FooterSection
```

```
footer.css:
.footer {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: auto;
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: var(--footer-bg);
}

.footer p {
  font-family: 'Inconsolata', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: var(--text-color);
}
```

I want that when there is a button that provokes the dark-theme it will change all the colors on the page.